# How to use a library on SAPWebIDE

Tags: sapui5, bootstrapping, sap-fiori, web-ide

i am trying to use the `openui5-googlemaps` library, but the WebIDE looks at a different path than my SAP-System then the app is deployed.

```
libs: ["sap.m", "sap.ui.layout", "sap.ushell", "openui5.googlemaps"],
```

my SAP-System looks at path `resources/openui5/googlemaps`. 
However this does not work in the WebIDE.
Any ideas why and how i can fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either change the path, or load via your index.

[API With Example](http://scn.sap.com/community/developer-center/front-end/blog/2014/07/01/google-maps-library-for-ui5)

[In Index](https://scn.sap.com/people/konstantin.anikeev/blog/2013/02/11/sapui5-with-google-maps)

~ update may 2017 ~ 
You can now use the manifest to add libraries:

```
"resources": {
    "css": [
        {
            "uri": "css/style.css"
        },
        {
            "uri": "css/croppie.css"
        }
    ],
    "js": [
        {
            "uri": "library/croppie.min.js"
        }
    ]
```

Comment: i have tried the example already, then it works on the webIDE but it stops working on my production system

Comment: Then the API is located in a different version compared to your WEBide. It's probably easiest to move the API around in your folder structure for the WEBide. To be sure, you can copy it. 
In the example it's located one folder back, hence the ../ If you copy it into the app folder structure, you can suffice without the ../